# How to get angle of swipe from javascript touch events

Tags: javascript, touch

I have the following code:

```
swipeDetect = function(el, callback){

    var touchsurface = el,
    swipedir,
    startX,
    startY,
    distX,
    distY,
    threshold = 7, //required min distance traveled to be considered swipe
    restraint = 100, // maximum distance allowed at the same time in perpendicular direction
    allowedTime = 500, // maximum time allowed to travel that distance
    maxangle=40,
    elapsedTime,
    startTime,
    touchinprocess=false,
    handleswipe = callback || function(swipedir){};

    touchsurface.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){

        touchinprogress = true;
        var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0];
        swipedir = 'none';
        dist = 0;
        startX = touchobj.pageX;
        startY = touchobj.pageY;
        startTime = new Date().getTime();
    }, false);

    touchsurface.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){


        var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0];
        distX = startX - touchobj.pageX;
        distY = startY - touchobj.pageY;
        rads = Math.atan(distY,distX);
        var deg = rads * (180 / 3.14);
        console.log(deg);
        if (Math.abs(distY) > restraint && Math.abs(deg) > maxangle) e.preventDefault();

    }, false);

    touchsurface.addEventListener('touchend', function(e){

        var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0];
        distX = touchobj.pageX - startX;
        distY = touchobj.pageY - startY;
        elapsedTime = new Date().getTime() - startTime;

        if (elapsedTime <= allowedTime){ // first condition for awipe met
            if (Math.abs(distX) >= threshold && Math.abs(distY) <= restraint){ // 2nd condition for horizontal swipe met
                swipedir = (distX < 0)? 'left' : 'right'; // if dist traveled is negative, it indicates left swipe
            }
            else if (Math.abs(distY) >= threshold && Math.abs(distX) <= restraint){ // 2nd condition for vertical swipe met
                swipedir = (distY < 0)? 'up' : 'down'; // if dist traveled is negative, it indicates up swipe
            };
        };
        handleswipe(e,swipedir);
        return true;
    }, false);
},
```

I'm trying to get the angle in degrees of a touch swipe in the touch move function (and kill the default scroll if the swipe is above a certain number of degrees). But It keeps outputting numbers around 80. No matter how I swipe. What is wrong here?

I'm using this for image swiping and I want to let the user swipe and not have it scroll and swipe at the same time.

Maybe i'm going about this all wrong.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Math.atan(x)`[1] function takes a single argument, which in your case should be the ratio of y over x:

`rads = Math.atan(distY/distX);`

It might be hard to see the difference, but in your initial code you have a `,` rather than a `/`. I ran your code with this change and it worked. Keep in mind that `Math.atan2(y,x)` does take two arguments.

[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete HTML solution using `touchstart`, `touchend`, `mousedown`, `mouseup`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    #swipe-area {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: aquamarine;
      border: 1px solid aqua;
      box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="swipe-area"></div>
<h2 id="angle"></h2>

<script>
  let swipeArea = document.getElementById('swipe-area');
  let startX = undefined;
  let startY = undefined;

  swipeArea.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
    startX = e.touches[0].clientX;
    startY = e.touches[0].clientY;
  });
  swipeArea.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
    let end = e.changedTouches[0];
    calculate(startX, startY, end.clientX, end.clientY);
  });

  swipeArea.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    startX = e.pageX;
    startY = e.pageY;
  });

  swipeArea.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
    calculate(startX, startY, e.pageX, e.pageY);
  });

  function calculate(startX, startY, endX, endY) {
    const distY = Math.abs(startY - endY);
    const distX = Math.abs(startX - endX);

    let angle = Math.atan2(distY, distX);

    // Convert from radians to degrees
    angle = angle * (180 / Math.PI);

    // Normalize the angle between 0 and 360 degrees
    if (angle < 0) {
      angle = angle + 360;
    }

    document.querySelector('#angle').innerHTML = `Swipe angle: ${angle.toFixed(0)}°`;
    console.log('Swipe angle: ' + angle);
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some testing and I think the issue may be with your atan function. Give atan2 a try?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2

It seems to essentially work for me.